# Statement to set certain courses live and some to draft

Tags: php, sql

I'm a very junior Laravel developer and I need help altering some "courses".

Tonight I need to set all courses within the table "`courses`" with the "`status`" of "`draft`" to "`published`" and all courses where their statues are not "`draft`" to "`draft`".

Their statuses can be:

```
"full"
"published"
"limited"
"cancelled"
"archived"
"inactive"
```

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE courses
SET status = CASE WHEN status = 'draft' THEN 'published' ELSE 'draft' END
```

In this particular instance, we don't need to use a `WHERE` clause, because you intend to update every record in the table.

Comment: Worked like a charm - Thanks so much :)